# Integral test: $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}f(n) = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\int_{n-1}^{n}f(n)dx$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

Having some trouble seeing why the following equivalence holds in the proof for Integral Test for convergent series.

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}f(n) = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\int_{n-1}^{n}f(n)dx$$

[image]

Comment: It's actually true that $\int_{m-1}^m f(n)\,dx = f(n)$, for any $m$. We're just picking a useful $m$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(n)$ is a constant (for the integral), hence

$$\int_{n-1}^n f(n) dx = f(n) \int_{n-1}^n dx = f(n) [ n-(n-1) ] = f(n)$$